# How to give Space between rows and columns of NSCollectionView?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nscollectionview

I have created collection view and I am unable to give space between the collection view items. So please help.... Thanks in advance...

I have used this link to create collection view https://andrehoffmann.wordpress.com/2009/08/29/nscollectionview-tutorial-for-dummies-xcode-3-1-3/

Comment: NO, I am using Xcode 6.1

Comment: Since it has been two years I'm not sure if that's going to be helpful now, but the closest I could be to achieve that in OS X was adding the space inside the NSCollectionViewItem view. Surely it isn't the best approach, however if your need to be compatible with 10.0 or below I think it's the only one (they added a way to do it on 10.11: https://www.raywenderlich.com/120494/collection-views-os-x-tutorial ).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using storyboard to create the collection view update the `Min Spacing` and `Section Inset` like

[image]

Comment: Alex thanks for your answer but I am creating collection view in cocoa application (Mac application) these option are not available there.

Answer (score -1):

You need to modify the CollectionView's layout. Probably the simplest thing to do is give it a Flow layout, and assign your properties there. Here's an example:

```
let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 5
layout.sectionInset = EdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
layout.minimumLineSpacing = 8
self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
```

If you want to do much more than this with respect to item layout, you'll need to subclass UICollectionViewLayout and override the various layout method.

Comment: Even though this answer uses the iOS-equivalent to NSCollectionView, it perfectly applies to Cocoa, as well, just swap UI with NS.